# I'm new to Responsive Design have with trouble designing for different resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**This is the page showing in resolution 1152*864**

[image: This is the screen showing resolution of 1152*864]

The same screen after I changed it to 1024*768 the things get messed up, I tried setting up `container-fluid` width to a static value the responsive design get spoiled.

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

[image: Page in resolution 1024*768]

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="span11" style="margin-top:4%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color: rgba(0, 4, 10, 0.71);padding: 5px;border-radius: 11px;"> 
    <li class="active"><a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: cursive;">Heading 1</a></li> 
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: cursive;">Heading 6</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some CSS and HTML?

Comment: Post some code. (And seriously, is that Comic Sans? o.O)

Comment: @BramVanroy Perhaps... ? http://divshot.github.io/geo-bootstrap/

Comment: @WesleyMurch Funniest thing EVER!

Comment: `<div class="span11" style="margin-top:4%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color: rgba(0, 4, 10, 0.71);padding: 5px;border-radius: 11px;">
              <li class="active"><a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: cursive;">Heading 1</a></li>
              <li>&nbsp;</li>
         
              
              <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: cursive;">Heading 6</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>  `

here is the code i'm using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to see your code I can only make some general suggestions:

1. Use `margin: 0 auto;` to horizontally center items on the page.
2. Use `max-width` to define the maximum width for items on a page.
3. Use `@media` queries to create breakpoints in your design.

   ```
   header{
       max-width: 960px;  /* The maximum width for your header item. */
       margin: 0 auto;    /* Center the header on the page. */
   }

   @media (max-width: 320px){
       header{
           /* Styles for screens less that 320px wide. */
       }
   }
   ```

Use this as a rough guide for making a simple design responsive. Also note that if `max-width`  isn't working try setting `width: 100%;` or `display: block;`

Comment: thank you @Rob `width:90%` actually solved my problem. Is that ok to give `<div class="span11"'>some text </div>` and setting up `width` to 97% because `span11` takes up default width of 876px

Comment: @yashhy Yeah, do what works for you :) I'm guessing your width of 90% is due to the padding of 5% on either side. However if you removed the width and used `display: block;` this would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great book on [**Responsive Design by Ethan Marcotte**](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). It will cover all topics of how to make responsive grid, responsive images and media queries + this is only 150 pages small free pdf :D

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries for Standard Devices from css-tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some margin right length to the Heading 6 element. Maybe that resolves you problem. Example:

`<style>
       li.pull-right {margin-right:1cm}
</style>`